# How to open Outlook msg files from disk using perl and Win32::OLE

Tags: perl, outlook, win32ole

I have a directory full of Outlook .msg files that I would like to process.
The processing will be to open the file and save the attachments. 
I have used Win32::OLE successfully to process messages in an Outlook folder, 
but these are files on disk. How can I open a msg file on disk and process it 
with perl and Win32::OLE?

**Restriction**: I work in an environment where I am not permitted to install anything on the machine.  In particular,  I cannot add other programs or perl modules. I am stuck with the modules that come with a fresh installation of perl.

Here is what I tried:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $OL = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application') ||
         Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application', 'Quit');
my $NameSpace = $OL->GetNameSpace("MAPI");

$File = Win32::GetFullPathName(".") . "\\" . "TestMessage.msg";
$msg  = $OL->Open($File);       ## Result is undefined
```

Solutions and or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Does Win32::OLE->LastError() show anything interesting?

Comment: @GeorgMavridis - Yes!   I get `Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x8002000e: "Invalid number of parameters"
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET `. I will try to track down documentation on `Open`

Comment: Did someone got a solution to this??

Comment: @Mohit.  No.  I tried to follow the error message, but never got a working example.

Comment: But I was able to do it

Answer (score 1):

I somehow after some research on the Internet got to the below code which does my work to extract attachments from a .msg file present on my local directory.Pass the .msg path to `$filename`

```
my $msg = new Email::Outlook::Message $filename;
my $data = $msg->to_email_mime;
my $stripper = Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper->new($data);
for my $a ($stripper->attachments()) {
    my $file = $a->{filename};
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
    print $fh $a->{payload};
    close $fh;
    chmod 0644, $file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This looks like this could be useful for most people, but unfortunately, this solution will not work for me. As I said in the **Restriction** part of my question, I cannot install additional perl modules in my working environment. I do have the Email module, but not Email::Outlook .

Comment: Sorry, this is a very bad situation getting tied to the old modules when we have new one's available.